# Intuitive understanding of measurability in probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

We know that a real function $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathrm{R} $ is $F-$measurable, where $(\Omega,\mathrm{F},P)$ is a measure space, if given a Borel set $B$, its counterimage $X^{-1}(B)$ belongs to  $\mathrm{F}$. This is the formal definition but I think it is worth asking what is an intuitive understanding/interpretation of this concept in the framework of probability theory ?

( E.g. this intuitive understanding/interpretation should serve to enlighten notations like $E[Y|F]$, $E[Y|X]$, $E[Y|\sigma(X)],...$, i.e. it should build an intuition on top of which more complex concepts of probability theory can be understood )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first try to understand intuitively what a $\sigma$-algebra represents.

- It is the collection of events that we know whether they have happened or not. Best to imagine two $\sigma$-algebras ${\cal F}_t$ and ${\cal F}_T$ where $t$ and $T$ are times and $t<T\,.$ A reasonable probability model will assume that at time $T$ we know in particular what had happened at time $t\,.$ Thus, formally ${\cal F}_t\subseteq {\cal F}_T\,.$ (See how that is used to define a filtration of a stochastic process). Also the laws defining a $\sigma$-algebra reflect exactly that if you know that $A$ has happened then $A^c$ has *not* happened. And so on.

Now to measurability:

- The simplest $\sigma$-algebra is $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}\,.$ This contains little information about what has happened. A function that is measurable w.r.t. this $\sigma$-algebra if and only if it is constant. A little more interesting $\sigma$-algebra is $\{\emptyset,A,A^c,\Omega\}\,.$ A function is measurable w.r.t. this $\sigma$-algebra if and only if
  $$
  f(\omega)=f_01_A(\omega)+f_11_{A^c}(\omega),
  $$
  that is, it can take only two values that indicate whether $A$ has happened or not.

A  general measurable function $f$ can be decomposed into its positive and negative parts $f^+$ and $f^-$. Each such part can be approximated by an increasing sequence of
"piecewise" constant (also called ***simple***) functions, ie., functions of the form
$$\tag{1}
f_n(\omega)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} 1_{A_k}(\omega)
$$
where $A_k$ are in the $\sigma$-algebra that makes $f$ measurable.
This is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2713231/proving-a-non-negative-measurable-function-is-the-limit-of-a-sequence-of-simple). One can obviously rewrite (1) as
$$\tag{2}
f_n(\omega)=\sum_{k=1}^n f^{(n)}_k 1_{A^{(n)}_k}(\omega)
$$
where $A^{(n)}_1,...,A^{(n)}_n$ are disjoint, measurable, cover $\Omega\,,$ and $f_k^{(n)}$ is the fixed value of $f_n$ on $A^{(n)}_k\,.$

- The measurability of $f$ is characterized by the coarsest $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal F}$ that makes $f$ measurable. In turn, this is characterized by how many simple functions $f_n$ we need to approximate it.

Comment: I think it is a useful intepretation. So we have our sample space $\Omega$ partitioned into "events", the elements of the $\sigma$ algebra. Given a sample point $\omega$, we can ask whether any of the events happened, i.e. we have a mapping $\rho_{\omega}: F \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. You want to say that in general $X$ is measurable if the value $X(\omega)$ is univocally identified by $\rho_{\omega}$ (i.e. by this "set" of answers) ?

Comment: If you mean by $\rho(\omega)$ the density of $X$ : *no* . The density is a function on the space where $X$ takes its values, not on $\Omega\,.$ Intuitively I imagine a "generally" measurable function by one that is to some extend approximated by "piecewise" constant functions. The coarseness of the $\sigma$-algebra that makes $X$ measurable tells how much information you gain about events by observing the random variable $X$.

Comment: By $\rho_{\omega}$ I meant something else actually. Take $f \in F$ an event in the $\sigma$ algebra (the "events") and define $\rho_{\omega}(f)=1$ if $\omega \in f$ and $0$ otherwise. That is the function I was referring to in the comment.

Comment: Also your last comment is helpful in developing the intution, would you mind expanding it into the answer ?

Comment: Will do. It looks like by $\rho_\omega$ you mean the indicator function of an event in ${\cal F}.$ I used $A$ instead of $f$ (you) which made a bit confusing what you meant. For a generally measurable $f$ (me) or $X$ (you) you should digest [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2713231/proving-a-non-negative-measurable-function-is-the-limit-of-a-sequence-of-simple).

Comment: They are related yes: $\rho_{\omega}(f)=1_{f}(\omega)$. But I was fixing $f$, so that in some sense it is the dual function. The idea is to list, given a sample point $\omega$, all answers to the question: "does $\omega$ belong to $f$?" or "did the event $f$ happen if we observe $\omega$". Building on your second example, I thought that the value of the function $X$ should be univocally identified by the answers to this question, i.e. by $\rho_{\omega}$

Comment: So trying to formalize a bit the previous comment to clarify. $X$ is is $F$-measurable when $"\rho_{\omega}=\rho_{\omega'} \Longrightarrow X(\omega)=X(\omega')"$. This to me would be an intuitive characterization, even if I am not sure how much it is correct. It tries to generalize your second example..

Comment: I think that the definition of $\rho$ for a general $X$ is void. Please digest the link I gave and what this has to do with my second comment above.

Comment: Mmm... the link says that a function can be written as pointwise limit of isotone simple functions. Simple functions are defined as linear combinations of indicator functions. Do not know what "isotone" means. The link with your answer I think you have to clarify, alongside what is a "void" definition and why my definition is void.

Comment: Of course you are not forced to post an answer to my question, if you do not want to clarify and follow up discussion ;)

Comment: Anyway, I can also open an other question to discuss the characterization I just proposed in the comment, since it is not part of your answer. If you clarify your second comment in the main question, and the relation to the other linked answer, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Please don't. Let's rather go to chat. Isotone means increasing. With that $\rho_\omega$ it seems you want to generalize the linear combination of indicator functions for a generally measurable $X\,.$ How do did you define $\rho$ before you wrote $\rho_\omega=\rho_{\omega'}\Rightarrow X(\omega)=X(\omega')$? I believe that the isotone limit is the way to go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134317/discussion-between-thomas-and-kurt-g).

Comment: OK. Looks like I can join this chat room only later today.

Answer (score 1):

Measurability means that $f$ makes sense as a random variable, i.e. it's compatible with the underlying probability space in such a way that it can be understood as a random experiment.

I think it could be useful to consider a probability space induced by a coin toss: Choose $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}$. Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, \quad \mathrm{if} \; x < 0 \\ 1, \quad \mathrm{if} \; x \geq 0 \end{cases}.
$$
Define two measurable sets on $\Omega$
$$
A_{\mathrm{heads}} = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{Z} \: \middle| \: x < 0 \right\} \\
A_{\mathrm{tails}} = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{Z} \: \middle| \: x \geq 0 \right\},
$$
which represent the two possible outcomes and let $ F = \left\{\varnothing, A_{\mathrm{heads}}, A_{\mathrm{tails}}, \mathbb{Z} \right\} $. Choose a probablity measure such that both $A_{\mathrm{heads}}$ and  $A_{\mathrm{tails}}$ are of measure 1/2.

Now another function
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} 0, \quad \mathrm{if} \; x < 1 \\ 1, \quad \mathrm{if} \; x \geq 1 \end{cases}
$$
is not measurable, because it's **incompatible** with the underlying probability space. In this simple scenario there is an easy explanation: The  values of $g$ do not correspond to possible outcomes. You can't deduce the value of $g$ by looking at the outcomes of the coin toss.

You could also observe that our $\sigma$-algebra is so simple that we can't have a random variable with more than two values. This again makes sense, because the probability space was specifically chosen to be suitable for coin toss.